# How to parse curl response when header is returned

Tags: php, xml, parsing, curl, xml-parsing

So what I am trying to do, is parse every "node" in the response for lack of better words. It should echo the "tag" followed by a ": " then the value. What I have tried is in the "Code" section. What gets returned from the current code is in the "Response" section. I'm trying to learn from others code and this is where the "Display headers / body / response for debugging and certification purposes" code comes from. I'm just trying to modify it to echo the parsed rawResponse when it clearly does not.

### **Response:**

```
    headers:
    body:
    rawResponse:AC700000005332001VI4788250000028291sBn551664C1A088C3242DF9CD5C92D52A8FA9EDD532D10100 N097857Approved00N013731
    OrderID: sBn5
    TxRefNum: 51664C1A088C3242DF9CD5C92D52A8FA9EDD532D
    RespCode: 00
    AVSRespCode: 
    CVV2RespCode: N
    AuthCode: 097857
```

### **Code:**

```
<?php

$xml_data = "<Request><NewOrder>";
$xml_data .= "<IndustryType>EC</IndustryType>";
$xml_data .= "<MessageType>AC</MessageType>";
$xml_data .= "<BIN>000002</BIN>";
$xml_data .= "<AccountNum>".$varCC."</AccountNum>";
$xml_data .= "<Exp>".$varExpiry."</Exp>";
$xml_data .= "<CardSecVal>".$varCVV."</CardSecVal>";
$xml_data .= "<OrderID>sBn5</OrderID>";
$xml_data .= "<Amount>".$varAmt."</Amount>";
$xml_data .= "</NewOrder></Request>";   

$URL = "https://orbitalvar1.paymentech.net";

// Build header as array for cURL option
$header = "POST /AUTHORIZE HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header.= "Content-type: application/PTI46\r\n";
$header.= "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_data)."\r\n";
$header.= "Content-transfer-encoding: text\r\n";
$header.= "Request-number: 1\r\n";
$header.= "Document-type: Request\r\n";
$header.= "Interface-Version: Test 1.4\r\n";
$header.= "Connection: close \r\n\r\n";              
$header.= $xml_data;   

// Define cURL options, then connect to server while saving response
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$rawResponse = curl_exec($ch);             

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
   print curl_error($ch);
} else {
   curl_close($ch);
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Display headers / body / response for debugging and certification purposes
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
echo "headers:<BR>\n";
foreach($header as $value) echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$value<BR>\n";
echo "<BR>body:<BR>\n&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$body<BR><BR><HR>\n";
echo "<BR>rawResponse:<BR>\n&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$rawResponse<BR><BR>\n";

// Parse rawResponse XML to response array, then only display important values
$parser = xml_parser_create('UTF-8');
xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $rawResponse, $response);
//var_dump($response);
foreach($response as $value){
    switch($value["tag"]){
        case "ORDERID": echo "OrderID: ".$value["value"]."<BR>\n"; break;
        case "RESPCODE": echo "RespCode: ".$value["value"]."<BR>\n"; break;
        case "AVSRESPCODE": echo "AVSRespCode: ".$value["value"]."<BR>\n"; break;
        case "CVV2RESPCODE": echo "CVV2RespCode: ".$value["value"]."<BR>\n"; break;
        case "TXREFNUM": echo "TxRefNum: ".$value["value"]."<BR>\n"; break;
        case "AUTHCODE": echo "AuthCode: ".$value["value"]."<BR>\n"; break;
    }
}unset($value);
?>
```

Comment: Your code is wrong. You misuse CUSTOMREQUEST, so the result will be a broken HTTP request being used.

Answer (score 2):

You neeed separate http headers from http body. It is a `"\r\n\r\n"` snting. So you can find it like this:

```
$p = strpos($rawResponse, "\r\n\r\n");
if( $p !== false ) {
    $rawHeades = substr($rawResponse, 0, $p);
    $rawBody = substr($rawResponse, $p + 4);
}
```

and you need some thing after `print curl_error($ch);` - in this case there isn't any true data in $rawResponse